# Changing variable in 2d array in a method

Tags: java, string, methods, tic-tac-toe, jagged-arrays

Basically I'm trying to make a tic tac toe game out of Java and in the choiceInputter method it seems that grid[row][column] doesn't want to change values in this method. I don't know why it's not working.

```
import java.util.*;

public class TicTacToe
{
public static void main (String args[]){
    String [][] gameGrid = new String [3][3];
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();
    int counter = 0; //checks whether game is at beginning or not
    boolean check = true;
    boolean player = true; //decides who's turn it is. Player 1 = true. Player 2 = false.
    boolean choice = false; //false for O, true for X
    String pick = new String(" "); //selects the player's piece
    String input = new String(" "); //placement/instruction/done choice for player 1 AND player 2
    String piece1 = new String(" ");
    String piece2 = new String(" ");
    sleep(500);
    System.out.println("Welcome to Tic-Tac-Toe! **Java Edition**");
    sleep(1000);
    //Player X or O start
    System.out.println("\nPlayer 1, would you like to be X or O?");
    pick = scan.nextLine();

    do {
        if(pick.equalsIgnoreCase("x")) {
        choice  = true;
        piece1 = "X";
        piece2 = "O";
        sleep(750);
        typedString(30,"\nPlayer 1, you are Xs.");
        sleep(500);
        typedString(30,"Player 2, you are Os.");
        check = true;
        }
        else if(pick.equalsIgnoreCase("o")){
            choice = false;
            piece1 = "O";
            piece2 = "X";
            sleep(500);
            typedString(30,"\nPlayer 1, you are Os.");
            sleep(500);
            typedString(30,"Player 2, you are Xs.");
            check = true;
        }
        else {
            sleep(500);
            System.out.println("\nThat is not a valid answer.");
            sleep(500);
            typedString(25,"Please choose again: X or O?");
            check = false;
        }
        sleep(750);
        System.out.println("\nThe game will now begin...");
    } while(check == false);
    //Player X or O end
    sleep(2000);
    typedString(25,"\nCreating new Tic-Tac-Toe grid...");
    blankGrid(gameGrid);
    sleep(1000);
    typedString(25,"Finding instructions to game...");
    sleep(1000);
    //Game start
    while(!input.equalsIgnoreCase("done")){
        if(counter == 0) {
            System.out.println("\nGame has started!");
            sleep(1000);
            typedString(50, "\nFor instructions on how to play type help.\n");
        }
        //help
        else if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("help")) {
            gameInstructions();
            input = " ";
            if(player) {
                player = false;
            }
            else {
                player = true;
            }
        }

        else{
            //player 1's go
            if(player) {
                    sleep(750);
                    System.out.println("Player 1's turn. Choose a place to put your " + piece1 + ".");
                    chooseGrid(gameGrid);
                    input = scan.nextLine();
                    choiceInputter(gameGrid, input, player, piece1, piece2);
                    sleep(750);
                    player = false;
/*                      sleep(500);
                    System.out.print("That is not a valid answer!\n");
                    sleep(500);
                    System.out.println("Remember you can always type 'help' if you don't know what to do.");
                    sleep(750);
                    input = " ";
                */
            }
            //player 2's go
            else if(!player){
                    sleep(750);
                    System.out.println("Player 2's turn. Choose a place to put your " + piece2 + ".");
                    chooseGrid(gameGrid);
                    input = scan.nextLine();
                    choiceInputter(gameGrid, input, player, piece1, piece2);
                    sleep(750);
                    player = true;
                    /*
                    sleep(500);
                    System.out.print("That is not a valid answer!\n");
                    sleep(500);
                    System.out.println("Remember you can always type 'help' if you don't know what to do.");
                    sleep(750);
                    input = " ";*/
                }
                displayGrid(gameGrid);
            }

            sleep(1000);
            counter++;
        }

    }
    //Game end
    /*
        *blankGrid: creates a blank Tic-Tac-Toe array template.
    */
public static void blankGrid(String[][] grid) {
    sleep(500);
    for(int row = 0;row<grid.length;row++) {
        for(int column = 0;column<grid[row].length;column++) {
            grid[row][column] = " ";
        }
    }
}
/*
    *displayGrid: Prints the current game grid at the end of the turn.
*/
public static void displayGrid(String[][] grid) {
    sleep(500);
    for(int row = 0;row<grid.length;row++) {
        for(int column = 0;column<grid[row].length;column++) {
            //not the last column and not X or O
            if(column<grid[row].length-1) {
                if((!grid[row][column].equalsIgnoreCase("X"))||(!grid[row][column].equalsIgnoreCase("O"))){
                    grid[row][column] = " ";
                    System.out.print(" " + grid[row][column] + " |");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.print(" " + grid[row][column] + " |");
                }
            }
            else{
                if(!grid[row][column].equalsIgnoreCase("X")||!grid[row][column].equalsIgnoreCase("O")){
                    grid[row][column] = " ";
                    System.out.print(" " + " " + " \n");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.print(" " + grid[row][column] + " \n");
                }
            }
        }
        if(row<grid.length-1){
            System.out.println("-----------");
        }
        else{

        }
    }
}
/*
    *chooseGrid: Prints the game grid with number locations for the Player to pick.
*/
public static void chooseGrid(String[][] grid) {
    sleep(500);
    int location = 1;
    for(int row = 0;row<grid.length;row++) {
        for(int column = 0;column<grid[row].length;column++) {
            //not the last column and not X or O
            if(column<grid[row].length-1) {
                if(!grid[row][column].equalsIgnoreCase("X")||!grid[row][column].equalsIgnoreCase("O")){
                    grid[row][column] = Integer.toString(location);
                    System.out.print(" " + grid[row][column] + " |");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.print(" " + grid[row][column] + " |");
                }
                location++;
            }
            else{
                if(!grid[row][column].equalsIgnoreCase("X")||!grid[row][column].equalsIgnoreCase("O")){
                    grid[row][column] = Integer.toString(location);
                    System.out.print(" " + grid[row][column] + " \n");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.print(" " + grid[row][column] + " \n");
                }
                location++;
            }
        }
        if(row<grid.length-1){
            System.out.println("-----------");
        }
        else{

        }
    }
}

/*
    *gameInstructions: Prints the game instructions if the Player inputs help
*/
public static void gameInstructions() {
    String instruct = new String("To pick the place you want your piece to go type the number at the location.\nUnfortunately, your actions can not be undone.\nThis game is multi-player.\nRemember its 'done' to end the game.");
    sleep(500);
    typedString(50,"\nInstructions: ");
    sleep(750);
    typedString(50,instruct);
    sleep(750);
    typedString(30," Have fun! :D\n");
}

/*
    *sleep: makes the console wait depending on the amount of miliseconds chosen
*/
public static void sleep(long milis) {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(milis);
            }
            catch(Exception ee) {}
}

/*
    *typedString: Prints a string as if it was being typed live
*/
public static void typedString(long time, String sentence) {
    for(int i = 0;i<sentence.length();i++){
        System.out.print(sentence.charAt(i));
        sleep(time);
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

/*
    *choiceInputter: Inputs the player's choice into the grid/array
*/
public static void choiceInputter(String[][] grid, String choice,boolean player, String piece1, String piece2) {
    if(player) {
        for(int row = 0;row<grid.length;row++) {
            for(int column = 0;column<grid[row].length;column++) {
                if(grid[row][column].equalsIgnoreCase(choice)) {
                    System.out.println("I'm working");
                    grid[row][column] = piece1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        for(int row = 0;row<grid.length;row++) {
            for(int column = 0;column<grid[row].length;column++) {
                if(grid[row][column].equalsIgnoreCase(choice)) {
                    System.out.println("I'm working");
                    grid[row][column] = piece2;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

}
```

### Update

I fixed it.

Comment: please post what you have tried and what you got from it. Also if you put the `if(player)` condition inside the loops you could remove alot of duplicated code

Comment: Moved the text above the code. This lets the reader have some focus for the code that follows

Comment: Did you try to debug your program?

Comment: Please post the relevant method instead of the entire program.

Comment: the else if(!player) is a totally redundant piece of code.

Comment: Hey guys I fixed my problem.I just had to change the || to && when checking to see if there is a X or O value on the array, in the displayGrid and chooseGrid method.

btw. the problem was that the X and O's weren't being saved in the array value the player chose.